# How to use a function to change every textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, function, css-selectors, textbox

I don't know, but I think there's probably a problem between the CSS selector and the JS function. I want to change the colors of the textarea and it's attributes (background color, color, and placeholder), which is something in can ✓ off the to do list.

However, for some reason it refuses to apply to any other textboxes. So it's just the already established preset values of the attributes. And I'm having issues with changing the values of `input[type="text"]` with a function, even when I use querySelector(). Here, check this  out.

```js
var bgColors = ["#FFFFFF", "#80C040", "#00FFFF", "#000000", "#000000"];
var textColors = ["#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00"];
var phColors = ["#808080", "#406020", "#008080", "#800000", "#808000"];
var idx = 0; //index
function setColor() {
  if (idx == 4) {
    idx = 0;
  } else {
    idx = idx + 1;
  }
  document.querySelector('input[type=text]').style.backgroundColor = bgColors[idx];
  document.querySelector('input[type=text]').style.color = textColors[idx];
  document.querySelector('input[type=text]').style.setProperty("--c", phColors[idx]);
}
```

```css
::placeholder {
  color: var(--c, #808080);
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here">
<button onclick="setColor()">change</button>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').forEach(function...)`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: `document.querySelector(...)` only retrieves the first matching element.

Comment: Right, use `querySelectorAll()` to get all matches that you can loop over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()` and loop over the result.

```js
var bgColors = ["#FFFFFF", "#80C040", "#00FFFF", "#000000", "#000000"];
var textColors = ["#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00"];
var phColors = ["#808080", "#406020", "#008080", "#800000", "#808000"];
var idx = 0; //index
function setColor() {
  if (idx == 4) {
    idx = 0;
  } else {
    idx = idx + 1;
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(el => {
    el.style.backgroundColor = bgColors[idx];
    el.style.color = textColors[idx];
    el.style.setProperty("--c", phColors[idx]);
  });
}
```

```css
::placeholder {
  color: var(--c, #808080);
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here">
<button onclick="setColor()">change</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and el means Element right?

Comment: Yes, it's my preferred abbreviation in when coding.